# Use print function for output of overloaded << operator?

Tags: c++, function

I have successfully overloaded the '<<' operator which I believe is referred to as the insertion operator.  I have a print function which prints the information of an instance of a card object, how can I call this print function when the operator is used

example:

```
Card aCard("Spades",8);  //generates an 8 of spades card object

aCard.Print(); // prints the suit and value of card

cout << aCard << endl;  // will print something successfully but how can I get the same results as if I were to call the print function?
```

In my implementation file `card.cpp` I have overloaded the << for use with my card class.

Card.cpp

```
void Card::Print()
{
    std::cout << "Suit: "<< Suit << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value:" << Value << std::endl;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Card &aCard)
{
    Print();//this causes an error in the program
}
```

Card.h

```
class Card
{
public:       
    std::string Suit;
    int Value;

    Card(){};
    Card(std::string S, int V){Suit=S; Value=V};

    void Print();

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Card&)
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You do only want one implementation.  You could either make a Print function that takes an `ostream` and performs all of the print logic then call it from `Print()` and `operator<<`

```
void Card::Print()
{
    Print(std::cout);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Card &aCard)
{
    Print(out);
}

void Card::Print(std::ostream &out)
{
    out << "Suit: "<< Suit << std::endl;
    out << "Value:" << Value << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

Or you could have the `operator<<` contain the print logic and call `operator<<` from `Print`:

```
void Card::Print()
{
    std::cout << *this;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Card &aCard)
{
     out << "Suit: "<< Suit << std::endl;
     out << "Value:" << Value << std::endl;
     return out;
}
```

Comment: You need to return the `ostream` from both of your versions.

Answer (score 0):

You need `aCard.Print()` in `operator<<` not `Print()`

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Card &aCard)
{
    aCard.Print();
}
```

You don't say what the error is but basically you're calling a globally defined `Print()` function or a function that doesn't exist with your code as it stands.

Comment: Well i receive an error saying my Print function is not defined in this scope, however when I use `aCard.Print()` I receive another error which states: error passing 'const Card' as `this` argument of `void Card::Print` discards qualifiers [-fpermisssive]

Comment: @JohnDream Right.  That is easily solved actually--just declare Print() `const`, i.e. `void Print() const;` in the class declaration and `void Card::Print() const { ... }` in the definition